# How to evaluate: $\int_0^1(-1)^{\ln(x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-numbers

So I was looking through the homepage of Youtube to see if there were any integrals that I might want to evaluate when I came across [this](https://youtu.be/FYXVvnJarBg?si=wwZvXjGB7_tqHQAN) video by Maths$505$ which showed how to evaluate$$\int_0^1(-1)^{\ln(x)}dx$$which I thought that I might be able to do (very easily at that). Here is my attempt at evaluating$$\int_0^1(-1)^{\ln(x)}dx$$

---

$$\begin{align}\int_0^1(-1)^{\ln(x)}dx\implies&\int_0^1\left(e^{i\pi}\right)^{\ln(x)}dx\\\implies&\int_0^1\require{cancel}\cancel{e}^{i\pi\cancel{\ln(x)}}dx\\\implies&\int_0^1x^{i\pi}dx\\\implies&\left.\dfrac{x^{1+i\pi}}{1+i\pi}\right]_0^1\\\implies&\left.\left(\dfrac{1-i\pi}{1-i\pi}\right)\left(\dfrac{x^{1+i\pi}}{1+i\pi}\right)\right]_0^1\\=&\left.\dfrac{(1-i\pi)x^{1+i\pi}}{1+\pi^2}\right]_0^1\\=&\dfrac{1-i\pi}{1+\pi^2}\\\approx0.091999668350375232-&0.289025482222236242i\end{align}$$which checking with [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29-1%5C%2841%29%2Cln%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D) shows that I, am in fact, correct.

---

#### My question

---

Since I seem to have evaluated the integral correctly, is there anything I could do to evaluate this integral more quickly?

Comment: First of all, it all depends on what you mean by $(-1)^y$ when $y$ is a real number. There are a lot of natural "branches" for this function, but the most basic is $(-1)^y=e^{i\pi y}=\cos(\pi y)+i\sin(\pi y).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, but then we would be stuck with evaluating $\int_0^1\cos(\pi\ln(x))+i\sin(\pi\ln(x))dx$

Comment: I would say it is dangerous to do the replacement, $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$ in complex numbers. Here, $a=e, b=\log x, c=i\pi.$ This replacement isn't always true in single-valued complex exponentiation. It works here fine, but you have to make an argument why.

Comment: Also, evaluating $x^{1+i\pi}$ at $x=0$ is suspicious. There is a reason we don't like to exponentiate $0$ in complex numbers - if we can't raise $0$ to the $-1$ power, why can  we say$0^i=0,$ and thus $0^{-1}=(0^i)^i=0?$

Comment: What we can say is that $x^{1+i\pi}\to0$ as $x\to0^+.$

Comment: Let $x=e^t$ which is the obvious substitution.

Comment: Right, substituting $x=e^t$ and you get $$\int_{-\infty}^0 e^t\left(\cos \pi t+i\sin\pi t\right)\,dt$$ You can solve the two integrals by integration by parts.

Comment: Avoid math videos for the sake of making progress. They are only good for entertainment. To learn something , read wikipedia- and pdf-articles.

Comment: @Peter Maths 505 started physics lectures now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x=e^t$. Then
$$\int_0^1(-1)^{\ln x}dx=\int_{-\infty}^0(-e)^tdt=\left.\frac{(-e)^t}{\text{Log}(-e)}\right\vert_{-\infty}^0=\frac{1}{1+\pi i}.$$

Comment: As discussed in the comments, the complex logarithm is a multi-valued function, so that $(-1)^{\ln x} = \exp(\ln(x) \cdot \ln(-1))$ is ambiguous without specifying which branch of the logarithm is chosen. In fact the answer depends on which branches are chosen. I would suggest that you address this in your answer.